# I align two TextViews but the second one does not show properly when the first one has a long line in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align two TextViews and place the second one in the right side of the screen in Android app.
But the second one gets cut off from outside screen.
If I write a short message on the first TextView, the second one shows up correctly.

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Hi, this line is long and affects right side " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Txt2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Txt1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: This is displayed]

Comment: What do you want to achive? Should the first text simply be cut off at a specific length? Should the second one always show in full or should the two views have a specific amount of space available (say, half the screen each). Shall the first text just span multiple lines?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I want to show the first and the second text in full and have an amount of 2/3 space available to the first text. The first text can span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:id="@+id/Txt1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:text="Hi, this line is long and affects right side " />

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:id="@+id/Txt2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Txt1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Something like this could work. Using layout weight in linear layout.

Comment: I tried it but I couldn't show the second textview in full.  It just shows up with only "Hello" message.

Comment: Then try changing weight for first textview from 0.75 to 1 and for second textview remove weight and make it's width wrap_content